# print and scan a string c

Tags: c, string, char, printf

I wanted to scan and print a string in C using Visual Studio.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    char name[20];
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", name);
    printf("%s", name);
}
```

After I did this, it doesn't print the name.
What could it be?

Comment: do you enter a name at command promt ?.. as by looking at the code, everything seems good

Comment: Yes, if I type my name, it doesn't write anything as output.

Comment: Does Visual Studio give a warning about `scanf_s("%s", name);`?  What version are you using?

Comment: I already fixed it with: scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name));

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting from [the documentation of `scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx),

> **Remarks:**
>
> [...]
>
> Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

So, the `scanf_s`

```
scanf_s("%s", &name);
```

is wrong because you did not pass a third argument denoting the size of the buffer. Also, `&name` evaluates to a pointer of type `char(*)[20]` which is different from what `%s` in the `scanf_s` expected(`char*`).

Fix the problems by using a third argument denoting the size of the buffer using `sizeof` or `_countof` and using `name` instead of `&name`:

```
scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name));
```

or

```
scanf_s("%s", name, _countof(name));
```

`name` is the name of an array and the name of an array "decays" to a pointer to its first element which is of type `char*`, just what `%s` in the `scanf_s` expected.